# Second display freaks out when waking from sleep

Tags: macbook, external-display, mini-displayport

I have two laptops, an older white MacBook and a brand new Macbook Pro. When either computer is on my desk, I connect it to a second, widescreen display (Acer, a couple years old, uses DVI). The Macbook connects via mini DVI and the MBP connects via mini displayport.

When the Macbook is connected and everything goes to sleep, I'm able to wake the machine and both displays in the normal way and everything is fine. Sometimes, when waking the MBP, the laptop and primary display are fine, but the second display shows a bunch of static. If I restart the display, everything's fine. This probably happens 70% of the time when the MBP goes to sleep while connected to this display.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried to switch the displays and see if the problem remains?

Comment: I haven't, but only because I don't have another display with which to exchange this one.

Comment: If restarting the monitor helps I'm pretty sure it's the monitors powersave mode that's broken. But You need to test that on another computer.